# Editing category-xxx.php just as editing a page

Tags: wordpress

I have several category-xxx.php each with a specific introductory text.

How to enable my client to edit this text in the dashboard, in the same manner as when he edits the content of a page ? (that is, NOT in appearance > editor)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [category_description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description) tag in your category template. Your user can then edit this text from "Posts > Categories" in the Admin area.